# Правильно ли написано?

Tags: пунктуация, редактура

Правильно ли написано? С пунктуацией верно? Может надо разделить предложение на два? "Как же я сразу не додумался!" "Постой! Как же я сразу не
додумался, если Люси ещё в море, надо развести костёр, тогда она увидит, что я здесь."

Answer (score 2):

В качестве варианта: **Постой, постой, как же я сразу не додумался! Если Люси ещё в море, то надо развести костёр, и тогда она увидит, что я здесь.**